Restrict number of concurrent consumers on shared JMS queue
I have multiple CXF web services consuming messages from the same JMS queue based on message selectors.
It is not ideal but it works and I am not going to challenge that.
For performance reasons, I'd like to be able to limit the number of consumers that can process messages at the same time.
I thought about CXF JMSConfiguration.concurrentConsumers parameter but it doesn't fit in my case: each service already has only one consumer.
The JMS broker I'm using is Joram.
